# RAID 1 system migrating using mdadm without loosing data from HDD

Tags: raid, mdadm

I'd like to migrate from one system with RAID 1 (array of 2 discs 3TB) to Ubuntu Server and create an array using mdadm. How can I do it and preserve data on those discs without formatting? Both drives are now mirrored and work well in the old system.

Comment: I am not at home right now in front of my system, but it can be done.  One thing to remember is that in a RAID1 either disk can work independently of the other one.  But you shouldn't have to format by adding it into the Server using mdadm.  You can do it with commands like `mdadm --assemble --scan`, and then add it to the `/etc/mdadm.conf` file by running `mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf`.  You can also see:  https://serverfault.com/questions/32709/how-do-i-move-a-linux-software-raid-to-a-new-machine

Answer (score -1):

To migrate from a system with RAID 1 to Ubuntu Server without formatting and preserving data, you can follow these steps. Please make sure that these steps are used only and only if the RAID array is in a healthy state:

It is a brief overview, so please take caution before using these steps.

**1. Install mdadm:** Ensure that `mdadm` is installed on your Ubuntu Server system. You can install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt install mdadm
```

**2. Identify Drives:** Identify the RAID drives you want to migrate. You can use tools like `lsblk`, `fdisk`, `parted`, `Gparted` `Gnome Ubuntu Disks(disk manager)` to list and identify the drives.

**3. Stop RAID Array on the Source System:** Before removing the drives, stop the RAID array on the source system. This will prevent any changes from being made to the RAID array while you are migrating.

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/mdX
```

Replace `/dev/mdX` with the appropriate RAID device identifier.

**4. Move Drives to the New System:** Physically move the RAID drives to the new Ubuntu Server system. Ensure that the drives are properly connected.

**5. Scan for RAID Arrays:** Scan for existing RAID arrays on the new system using the following command:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
```

This will attempt to assemble any detected RAID arrays.

**6. Check RAID Array Status:** Check the status of the RAID array to ensure it has been detected and is in a healthy state:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Verify that the RAID array is marked as `clean` and that both drives are listed.

**7. Mount RAID Array:** If the RAID array is not automatically mounted, you may need to mount it manually. Create a mount point and mount the array:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/raid
sudo mount /dev/mdX /mnt/raid
```

Replace `/dev/mdX` with the appropriate RAID device identifier.

**8. Update `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`:**
Update the `mdadm.conf` file to ensure that the RAID array is assembled correctly on boot. Run the following command:

```
sudo mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

This will add the RAID configuration to the `mdadm.conf` file.

**9. Update `/etc/fstab` (Optional):** If you want the RAID array to be mounted automatically on boot, you can add an entry to /etc/fstab. Edit the file using a text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add a line similar to the following:

```
/dev/mdX    /mnt/raid    ext4    defaults    0    0
```

**10. Reboot:** Reboot the system to ensure that the RAID array is assembled and mounted automatically.

```
sudo reboot
```

**11. Verify:** After rebooting, check the status of the RAID array:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Verify that the array is active and both drives are listed.

Your RAID array should now be migrated to the new Ubuntu Server system without formatting or losing data. Double-check the data on the array to ensure it's accessible and intact.